# Alternatives to Electron IPC for Large Messages

Tags: performance, redux, websocket, electron, ipc

I have a React/Electron app split into 2 (and optionally many more) processes - a frontend, a backend, and potentially many 'inspector' windows. They are all connected via Redux using [redux-electron-store](https://github.com/samiskin/redux-electron-store) which keeps all the instances in sync using IPC, with the main process being the 'master' node, renderers being sent diff actions. The backend processes lots of images and XML, potentially hundreds, and sends them to Redux for storage, resulting in the entire thing hanging. The frontend requires the thumbnails, and both other windows require the parsed XML data.

Originally, I was sending each item as its own Redux action, resulting in like, 200 actions for example, which froze it. I also tried staggering these, sending one every 2 seconds or so, which was good, until performance started degrading part way through anyway. I then changed that to a batch process, of 1 action for each type of processing - thumbnails or parsing XML - for a group of files, which resulted in 2 payloads of 48MB and 37MB or similar, which was better, but still froze everything for a good few seconds.

I put a little interval counter in the main process to see if it was a main or renderer hang, and it seems the main process is freezing, presumably while it ingests and resends these big messages (naturally this is not a very foolproof method of establishing causation here). So I'm not really sure how to restructure things to stop freezing the main process. We had two ideas:

1. Abstract the thumbnail and XML data to a different part of Redux that won't be synced by IPC, and instead have a small local websocket server in the backend which can communicate straight to the process that requests the data, which will put it in its own Redux, and not sync it. This might be able to be done with WebWorkers? This should circumvent sending big payloads to the main process, and the web worker should avoid freezing the renderer.
2. A partner's idea was to have a local database that is presumably read/written to, and other windows would somehow need to be notified, and potentially store it in component state rather than Redux. I'm not as fond of this, due to introducing more I/O operations, needing to maintain this file, and some additional patch to notify components that need it, that the writing is done, to then go read the same data.

The IPC is all done async currently, though it still blocks.

This is all under the impression that the large messages freezing the renderer is the sole problem, and not Redux doing things with it, which may also be true, however removing it from being synced as in solution 1 would cover both of these.

If anyone has any ideas with how to better structure this, I'd be very appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

If sharing these actions between renderers only is a requirement and all renderers have the same origin you can try [BroadcastChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API) as an alternative to IPC.

Also you can try to handle the data in renderer process and send the update to other rendere without involving manin process at all.